# how to add common fields to models in prisma (schema)

Tags: typescript, model, schema, prisma

I have a problem with Prisma that is I have so far these models:

```
User, Branch, Project, Unit
```

and I need to add common fields like:

```
createdBy, CreatedAt, updatedAt, deleted
```

to all models and the models to come

I know I can add them manually (same fields each model) but it would be better if I added them one time

can anyone help me?

thanks a lot

Comment: Adding createdBy, createdAt, updatedAt, and deleted as common fields in my own opinion doesn't look and feel right. At a point in the application, you would perform certain actions on each separate model and you would want to keep track of these fields for each specific model.

Comment: i've made it by putting those in each model in the schema and handle them by prisma middleware for createdAt, updatedAt and soft delete and hard delete